# asciidoctor - offline user manual is nowhere to be found

Tags: asciidoctor

Does anyone know where to get an offline version of the Asciidoctor's user manual: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/

It is weird, how developers brag about Asciidoctor being able to export to PDF, HTML... But at the same time they fail to present a nice PDF document for offline use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the raw adoc source from: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor.org/blob/master/docs/user-manual.adoc and convert it using asciidoctor.

Feel free to grab the result directly from:

- https://sqli.dev/asciidoctor/user-manual.pdf (asciidoctor-pdf threw a few errors with this document, which I haven’t investigated, so some things may not show up as intended)
- https://sqli.dev/asciidoctor/user-manual.html (this html will still fetch online resources for fonts, mathjax, etc.)

You can use the following to limit the amount of online resources needed:

```
git clone https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor.org.git
cd asciidoctor.org/docs
curl -O https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip
7z x font-awesome-4.7.0.zip
asciidoctor -a !iconfont-remote=@ -a icons=font -a stylesdir=font-awesome-4.7.0/css -a !webfonts=@ user-manual.adoc
```

The resulting user-manual.html will only try to fetch the MathJax.js from a remote site.

I would recommend to open an issue at https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor.org proposing that they offer offline download options.